# How can I use partial views in Prism?

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism

I have Prism 7.1 with Xamarin Forms 3.5.  I can't get partial views to work correctly.

The consuming view has this up the top

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
             xmlns:prism="clr-namespace:Prism.Mvvm;assembly=Prism.Forms"
             prism:ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModel="True"
              xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:MapManPrism.Converters"
             x:Class="MapManPrism.Views.WelcomeWizardPage" 
             xmlns:mvvm="clr-namespace:Prism.Mvvm;assembly=Prism.Forms"
             x:Name="wizard"
             Title="Welcome" xmlns:cv="clr-namespace:PanCardView;assembly=PanCardView"
             xmlns:cvi="clr-namespace:PanCardView.Controls;assembly=PanCardView" xmlns:views="clr-namespace:MapManPrism.Views">
```

As you can see I am giving the consuming page a name (wizard).

I then have a carouselview that has several views in it

```
  <cv:CarouselView SelectedIndex="{Binding CurrentPage}" IsPanSwipeEnabled="false" IsUserInteractionEnabled="false">
            <cv:CarouselView.ItemsSource>
                <x:Array Type="{x:Type View}">
 <ContentView Padding="10" Margin="10">
...
 </ContentView>
     <ContentView>
                        <Frame>
                              <views:PublisherDetails mvvm:ViewModelLocator.AutowirePartialView="{x:Reference wizard}"></views:PublisherDetails>
                        </Frame>
                    </ContentView>
```

In my app.xaml.cs I have this line

```
 ViewModelLocationProvider.Register<PublisherDetails, PublisherDetailsViewModel>();
```

But I can't navigate to the consuming page when its set up like this.  Removing "mvvm:ViewModelLocator.AutowirePartialView="{x:Reference wizard}"" makes it work, but obviously the view model for the partial view doesn't get wired up.

How can I fix this? Or, is there a way to manually connect the partial view's view model to see if that fixes it?

Comment: without a sample that reproduces the issue it's very hard to diagnose. at first glance you have the Prism.Mvvm namespace brought in as both mvvm and prism... you only need it once... unrelated but you're also making too much use of ContentView's you don't need.

Comment: I just used ContentView because it seemed like a logical place to stash all my stuff... is there something I should use instead? I'll try to create a repro project...

Comment: Well, the test project works fine.  You know what that means! Its my fault.  The partial view works in one other area of the app, but not this area :( It fails completely silently too...

Comment: Putting the partial view outside of the Carousel works fine.  This is the carousel: https://github.com/AndreiMisiukevich/CardView.  I'll have to look into it some more... I can't see any reason why it wouldn't work in that :(

Comment: So, turns out CardsView is incompatible with PartialViews.  I made an issue on their github with a repro project incase you are interested? https://github.com/AndreiMisiukevich/CardView/issues/168